# When do Star tortoise lay eggs

Tags: breeding, tortoises

I have a pair of Indian Star tortoise. I have make them to stay together since last one month. What is duration that my female will lay egg after breeding? Also How much time it will take for a baby to comeout once the eggs has been laid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://startortoises.net/breeding.html

This is a pretty good site for your tortoise needs, has all the info. :)

"Incubation in captivity, the average is around 90-120 days depending on the incubation temperature."

Can take around 60-90 days for her to lay after mating.